# Delete User Data every 24 hours, node.js postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, cron

end is using express and postgres as its DB. Currently my schema is

```
.createTable('users', users => {
            users.increments();
            users.string('email').unique().notNullable();
            users.integer('total_points').defaultTo(0);

            // Everything below this needs to reset back to 0 every 24 hours

            users.integer('daily_points').defaultTo(0);
            users.integer('food').defaultTo(0);
            users.integer('sleep').defaultTo(0);
            users.integer('water').defaultTo(0);
```

How can I use node cron to delete data every 24 hours.

```
cron.schedule("* * * * *", function() {   // every day at 4am = 0 4 * * *
    console.log("running a task every minute");
  });
```

What can I pass in here instead of the console.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) module and write this in your server:

```
schedule = require('node-schedule');

schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 4 * * *',
  function (fireDate) {
    console.log(`fireDate: ${fireDate}`);
    console.log(`now: ${new Date()}`);
    yourRemoveFunction()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(`data removed at ${new Date()}`);
        console.log('result:\n', result);
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        console.error(`removing data failed at ${new Date()}`);
        console.error(`reason: ${reason}`);
      });
  });
```

Write a function which run the query to remove your target data(`yourRemoveFunction`)

Comment: Could I just inside my yourRemoveFunction()  ```return db(everything I need to delete).del() ?```  .. thank you for the previous answer as well!

Comment: It should return promise. @ShawnP96

Comment: yeah I tried my previous function, but it just deleted the entire user instead of resetting a field. What would I pass into my promise .then? I'm a little new, can't seem to find any documentation on this either.

Comment: You can define some repetitive formal tasks with node-schedule. So Your function is wrong. What's exactly that function? @shawnp96

Comment: I actually figured it out, a very simple solution. ```return db('users).update(daily_points=0, etc etc)``` Although I don't think this is the most secure way to do it. I found it on knexjs.org   @Saeed